# parallelisation sum in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table (Test) which contains 10 millions of records and I am considering the following simple query:

```
explain (costs off) select (
    (select count(value) from Test)
    +(select count(value) from Test)
    +(select count(value) from Test)
    +(select count(value) from Test));
```

I expected that its subqueries were executed in parallel, but:

1. the execution time grows linearly over the number of subqueries, even though their total number is less than the number of CPUs on my server (and there are available workers);
2. the output of the query is

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Result                                                                       |
  InitPlan 1 (returns $1)                                                    |
    ->  Finalize Aggregate                                                   |
          ->  Gather                                                         |
                Workers Planned: 4                                           |
                ->  Partial Aggregate                                        |
                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on Test test  |
  InitPlan 2 (returns $3)                                                    |
    ->  Finalize Aggregate                                                   |
          ->  Gather                                                         |
                Workers Planned: 4                                           |
                ->  Partial Aggregate                                        |
                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on Test test_1|
  InitPlan 3 (returns $5)                                                    |
    ->  Finalize Aggregate                                                   |
          ->  Gather                                                         |
                Workers Planned: 4                                           |
                ->  Partial Aggregate                                        |
                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on Test test_2|
  InitPlan 4 (returns $7)                                                    |
    ->  Finalize Aggregate                                                   |
          ->  Gather                                                         |
                Workers Planned: 4                                           |
                ->  Partial Aggregate                                        |
                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on Test test_3|
```

which shows that there is one Gather for each subquery.

So in the end I guess that the subqueries are not executed in parallel, even though they could be. Could you help me understanding why and if there is anything I can do to make them run in parallel?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The individual branches of the sum (each count) run in parallel instead so you are already maxing out your cores. Try increasing the record count, you should observe the execution time increasing by roughly a quarter the relative difference

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But the DBMS keeps optimising each internal subquery  with 4 workers even though the total number of subqueries increases (also in this case, the number of CPUs is way bigger). I guess that workers do not scale up because the size of the table is constant. In other terms, in this way I think the size of the table limits the speedup that could be achieved.

Comment: What is your max_parallel_workers_per_gather set to?

Comment: The number is 64.
If my assumption is correct it implies that, by selecting a specific size of the table, we may end up in a scenario where only one thread is used for the whole query, even though the global workload would justify the execution in parallel with several of them.

Comment: Can you come up with a more realistic example?  Presumably here you would just select once and multiply the count by 4.  So what are you really doing that you wouldn't just do that?

Comment: Hi. What I am really working on it's just a query built on unions of selects (union all). I don't think showing the code is helpful for the sake of clarity. The main point is that I am experiencing exactly the same problem, i.e. subqueries that are not executed in parallel even though, in my opinion, it would be beneficial as the workload is embarrassingly parallel. So I came up with this example to show the concept by removing what it is not relevant for the understanding.

Comment: It's not an area I've got experience with but the docs suggest you could (and maybe should) benefit from parallel append; at least in the union all case. Do you have it enabled? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-plans.html#PARALLEL-APPEND

Comment: In the example query here there is no append so it doesn't kick in, of course.

Comment: Hi @wobr, thanks a lot for your time. Yes I checked and it is enabled.